# Ruby をインストールせずに Ruby を使える環境にするためには？

Tags: ruby

【環境】CentOS7.2

Linux環境にて、RubyをインストールせずにRubyを使える環境にさせるにはどのような方法があるでしょうか？

Rubyのスクリプトで書かれた hoge.rb というスクリプトを作成したのですが、相手の環境には Ruby がなく実行出来ません。

相手の環境に Ruby をインストールしてもらえればいいのですが、こだわりがあるらしくRubyは入れたくない！依存関係が～という良くわからない理由があるため困っております。

ただ、fluentdなどを例にみると /opt/配下に Ruby? の環境が入っているらしくfluentdを使うときはRubyをインストールしなくても使えております。

fluentdのようにRubyをインストールせずともRubyが使えるようにするにはどうしたらよろしいでしょうか？
ご存じの方いらっしゃいましたらご教示頂けませんでしょうか？
または、そのあたりの部分について詳しく記載されているサイト等ございましたらご紹介して頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: rubyだけ入ってればいいのでしょうか？Gemとか依存関係のあるものはありますか？rubyだけで良ければ fluentd の ruby を使えば実行出来そうに思えます。

Comment: 「fluentdのように」というのは単に例であって、「相手の環境にfluentdが入っているといる」ことではない、という理解でいいでしょうか

Comment: @take88
回答ありがとうございます！
はい、fluentdのrubyを使えば実行できるのですが、そうではなく@suzukisさんが言っている内容の通りとなります。正確に質問できず申し訳ございませんでした。

Comment: @suzukis 回答ありがとうございます！はい、おっしゃる通りです。fluentdはあくまで「例」として出したものとなります。@take88 さんの2番目の回答（ソースからビルドした・・・）に近い感じがするので調べてみようと思います。
本当は「hoge.rb と ruby 環境一式を rpm 化して 相手に渡す感じ」の方が近いかもしれませんが。。。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Traveling Ruby](http://phusion.github.io/traveling-ruby/)とか参考になるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ただ、特定の相手の為だけにこういう作業をするのは無駄だと思います。Rubyのインストールもできないような環境では、これからもどんな問題が出てくるか分かった物ではありません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
初めてみました。[Traveling Ruby lets you create self-contained Ruby app packages for Windows, Linux and OS X]。。。なんと、これも私がやりたいことができそうな感じがしますね。調べてみようと思います！

Answer (score 4):

おそらく fluentd (td-agent) を rpm から入れているのではと思いますが その場合 /opt/td-agent/embedded/ に Ruby の環境が 組み込まれます。

「fluentdのように」やるのであれば hoge.rb と ruby 環境一式を rpm 化して 相手に渡す感じになりますが rpm 化はあまり詳しくないのでこれ以上のことは分からないです。すみません。

別の方法として思いつくのは

1. fluentd の ruby 環境を使ってもらう
2. ソースからビルドしたバイナリを相手に送る

**fluentd の ruby 環境を使ってもらう**

fluentd (td-agent) に組み込まれている ruby を使って実行できるかもしれません。

(例)

```
$ vim hoge.rb
#!/opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/ruby  <- fluentdのRuby
print "Hello World\n";

$ ./hoge.rb
Hello World
```

**ソースからのビルドしたバイナリを相手におくる**

ビルドした rubyのバイナリ環境ごと、相手に送付すれば良いと思います。
※ただし、この方法は 依存関係を自動的に解決出来ませんので 依存関係不足で実行出来ない可能性もあります。

(例)

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/var/tmp/hoge/
$ make
$ sudo make install

$ vim /var/tmp/hoge/bin/hoge.rb
#!/var/tmp/hoge/bin/ruby
print "Hello World\n";

$ chmod +x /var/tmp/hoge/bin/hoge.rb
$ /var/tmp/hoge/bin/hoge.rb
Hello World

$ tar cfz hoge.tgz -C /var/tmp ./hoge
$ ls hoge.tgz
hoge.tgz  ←このファイルを相手に送る
```

```
$ tar xfz hoge.tgz -C /var/tmp         ←/var/tmp/hoge に展開してもらう
$ /var/tmp/hoge/bin/hoge.rb
Hello World
$ rm -rf /var/tmp/hoge                 ←使い終わったらまるごと消す
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！
[ソースからのビルドしたバイナリを相手におくる]こちらが私のやりたいことに非常に近いため、参考にさせて頂こうと思います。

Comment: 様 申し訳ございません。せっかくこのようなたくさんの記述を頂いたのですが、@mjy 様のTraveling Ruby が完全に私のやりたいことにマッチしておりましので、解決ボタンをそちらでおさせて頂きました。この度はありがとうございます。

Comment: ぜんぜんokですよ〜。私も勉強になりましたので有り難いです。